# How can one use the Bible to determine if the beast with seven heads and ten horns is the G-7 nations plus three more?

Tags: revelation, dispensationalism

In Revelation, there are several references to the beast with seven heads and ten horns rising to world power.

> Rev. 12:3 And there appeared another wonder in heaven; and behold a great red dragon, having seven heads and ten horns, and seven crowns upon his heads.

> Rev. 13:1 And I stood upon the sand of the sea, and saw a beast rise up out of the sea, having seven heads and ten horns, and upon his horns ten crowns, and upon his heads the
> name of blasphemy.

> Rev. 17:3 So he carried me away in the spirit into the wilderness: and I saw a woman sit upon a scarlet coloured beast, full of names of blasphemy, having seven heads and ten
> horns.

> Rev. 17:7 And the angel said unto me, Wherefore didst thou marvel? I will tell thee the mystery of the woman, and of the beast that carrieth her, which hath the seven heads and ten horns.

How can a Bible reader determine if the seven heads refer to the G-7 seven nations? And the three extra horns could be when Russia, India, and China join them? https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/why-canada-failed-to-emerge-as-a-power-like-uk-or-france/7741#7741

**Note:** This is the revised version of a previously closed question. The original version was in the format, "Is it true that...?" This version is, "how can one determine if it is true that...?

Comment: One thing to ponder: `How can seven heads have ten horns?` If each head has 1 horn, we have 7 horns. If each head has 2 horns, we have 14 horns. How is it possible to have 10 horns? 3 heads need to have 2 horns.

Comment: How to handle this question topic on this site is being discussed over on meta: [Do Eschatology questions belong on Biblical Hermeneutics?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1506)

Comment: A much better case could be made for the European Union than for the G-7.
See: [Statue of Woman riding a Beast outside E.U. Council building in Brussels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Statue_of_Europa_outside_Council_building_in_Brussels.jpg) or [Image of Queen of Heaven with Blue Background and 12 Stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvu0c.jpg) which is identical to the E.U. flag.

Comment: @RayButterworth: Fair enough. But the revised question is, "How can we use the Bible to tell which one?' Will you vote to reopen it?

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure what will happen, but it's often easy to say what won't. In this case, consider that there will be an invading army of 200 million (Rev.9:16), and that could come only from the combined forces of Russia, India, and China (who contain nearly 40% of the world's population). So those three countries cannot possibly be part of the beast nation. And consider Ezekiel 38:3, "*Behold, I am against you, O Gog, the prince of Rosh, Meshech, and Tubal.*", where it's easy to map the last three names to "Russia", and to Moscow" and "Tobalsk", its western and eastern capitals.

Answer (score 5):

First, as with any question concerning prophecy, the answer is always *"Maybe."* It largely hinges on whether you think the prophecy has already occurred or not, and also on whether you think the prophecy will occur relatively quickly or not. Since you seem to be asking from the perspective that it has not occurred yet and will occur relatively quickly I will attempt to answer from that perspective.<sup>1 2</sup>

The [G-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G7), or Group of Seven, is primarily concerned with world economics, and has historically been comprised of nations that contain at least 50% of the world's wealth. The idea that a financial group could be the beast that Revelation refers to, in light of the kind of power that the beast is later said to have, does not seem far fetched. Consider this quote [generally attributed](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7887/what-did-rothschild-actually-mean-by-this-famous-quote) to a very prominent international banker of the 19th century.

> "Give me control of a nation's money and I care not who makes it's laws" — [Mayer Amschel Bauer Rothschild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer_Amschel_Rothschild)

However, this does not pinpoint the G-7. There are many financial groups that hold very much power over certain nations and their population. With some purposeful ambiguity '7' and '3' of anything can be found in any group. [The Federal Reserve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fed), for example has seven members of its [Board of Governors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fed#Board_of_Governors). One might suppose that the incorporation of three more is the beast. I would not be surprised if this theory does legitimately exist, but here and now I independently conceived it. Which shows my point.

The inclusion of these three ambiguous nations into the G-7 is just as ambiguous as the inclusion of three hypothetical persons into the Board of Governors. Especially considering there has already been a [G-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G8) as well.

All this is said with a healthy amount of skepticism, but not total convincing that there is no way the G-7, The Fed, or any other financial institution is not the beast. As mentioned at the top, it is really hard to tell what prophecy is referring to until it has already occurred.

---

1. For personal edification I urge you to consider this prophecy as one that might have already happened or is even happening now. I think this idea is largely ignored by Christians.
2. *Misc Notes about Revelation:* This particular book is filled with prophecy. Literally, it is almost entirely prophecy which is what makes it so hard to understand. There is a lot to consider when evaluating something as fulfilling a part of Revelation, therefore, I say that your question is a bit loaded and surely at least 20 pages could be written on the possibility of G-7 being the beast.